# Create view from fetching all rows (calling a function returning a cursor)

Tags: postgresql

In postgreSQL I have successfully managed to make a function which returns a refcursor where in a second step all rows can be fetched.

I would like to create a view with the records returned from the function, but I cannot figure out how this could be achieved (if at all) as the `SELECT` statement only returns the cursor but not the records. These need to be fetch with `FETCH ALL FROM`.

This is the function (it's basically a modification of what is explained in [this blog post](http://okbob.blogspot.de/2008/08/using-cursors-for-generating-cross.html)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_cross_cursor()
RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE
col_list text[] := '{}';
query text;
r RECORD;
result refcursor := 'result';
BEGIN
FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT DISTINCT jahrmonat::text FROM susa2'
LOOP
col_list := array_append(col_list, 'SUM(CASE jahrmonat WHEN'
 || quote_literal(r.jahrmonat) || ' THEN wert_monat_kum'
 || ' ELSE 0 END) AS ' || quote_ident(r.jahrmonat) || '');
END LOOP;
query := 'SELECT pk, '
 || array_to_string(col_list, ',')
 || ', SUM(wert_monat_kum) AS Total FROM susa2 GROUP BY pk';
 OPEN result NO SCROLL FOR EXECUTE query;
RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

I get my data with subsequently executing:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT do_cross_cursor();
FETCH ALL FROM result;
END;
```

In there a way to let `FETCH ALL FROM result;` flow into a view?

Comment: I'm pretty you can't do that. The view that would result would have a variable/dynamic number of columns based on whatever was "crossed" and the data in the table for that particular crossed field, so essentially, the resulting set of data has a dynamic schema. Fine for a cursor, not so for a view.

Answer (score 0):

answering your question: no. view requires all columns defined and you can't put fetch to view definition. But you can workaround. smth like:

```
select DISTINCT 
pk, jahrmonat,count(1) over (partition by pk,jahrmonat), SUM(wert_monat_kum) AS Total 
FROM susa2
```

should give you same data, vertically, so you [can try](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) `crosstab` to transfrom it to your data set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been trying to achieve my desired result with `crosstab` before and had the same issue that the number of pivoted columns is dynamic. Maybe I have to overthink my application / sql design a bit.